# Recommended minimum dimensions for touch areas for use with winter gloves

Tags: gui-design, touch-screen

Are there any guidelines, recommondations or research about using touch screens with winter gloves? I'm aware of the normal recommended defaults (44pt according to Apple's HIG, 48pt in Material Design), but those are minima.

Winter gloves come in different sizes and thicknesses, so I guess bigger touch areas are better, but I'm not sure of the thickness actually linearly correlates with precision. After all, it's not about the area covered by the glove on press, but about the pixel position that's converted to by the touch screen driver. Theoretically, a trained user with gloves could be as precise as one without any.

Comment: Can you provide some context to the reason for the question? This is a very specific question.

Comment: If users are wearing gloves often enough, you could capitalize on it by embracing it. Have a big button to hit to go to 'glove mode' which has big buttons.

Comment: The design is for an app for people underway on a bicycle. From experience I know that routing apps I’ve used are hard to handle with gloves on.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here is to test it directly. Recruit a few users, ask them to bring their gloves with them, and test various sizes. It will obviously be larger than 44pt or 48pt, but how large it depends only on the user.